# Pool redundancy analysis results from multiple imputations of missing data

Tags: r, missing-data, data-imputation, pooling, mice

I have a dataset that includes missing values, and **I would like to carry out redundancy analysis using multiple imputation to fill in the missing values**.
So far, I have successfully created multiple imputations of the dataset using the `mice` package in R. I can then carry out redundancy analysis on each of those datasets separately, but **how can I pool their results to create a single output**? Ideally I would like to produce ordination scores in order to create a triplot, as well as pseudo-F values and p values for the marginal effects of my predictor variables.

The `pool` function within the package doesn’t have a method for `.cca` objects, and what I have read about “Rubin’s Rules” seems to apply to linear models and similar, I have not been able to make the link with the kind of output I see from the RDA.

Below is some example code that shows what I have managed so far and where I am stuck. It’s based on the example on the `vegan::cca` help page, with the addition of multiple imputation. It’s therefore heavily simplified compared to the full process I would follow with my data. For example, the `mice()` step gives a bunch of warnings, but please ignore them, they are not the focus of the question.

```
# Load up packages and example dataset
library(vegan)
library(mice)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)

# Sprinkle some NA values into the data
dune.miss <- dune
for (i in 1:ncol(dune)) {
  dune.miss[,i] <- ifelse(runif(nrow(dune)) < 0.1, NA, dune[,i])
}

# Use MICE to impute missing values (5 imputations)
dune.imp <- mice(dune.miss)

# Select the first imputation and carry out RDA
dune.imp.1 <- complete(dune.imp, 1)
RDA <- rda(dune.imp.1 ~ Manure, dune.env)

# Examples of useful output
scores(RDA, choices = 1:2, scaling = 3, display = "bp")
anova.cca(RDA, by = "margin")
```

Clearly I could repeat the RDA step for each of the 5 imputations, but then how would I pool the above results to give a single output?